# Vector CRS change 'extents too large'

Tags: coordinate-system, vector, error, wgs84

Just trying to update an old project but for some reason it was set up in  EPSG:4326, WGS 84. I have no idea what base maps were originally used to create it as they are no longer on the system, and even with 'on the fly' enabled whenever I load a map in it says the extents are too large, if I reproject them they end up off the coast of Angola.
If I try loading Bing first then add the layers, it simply wont zoom to them and if I re-project the layer at that point it ends up off the coast of Angola and not in Somerset (where it belongs).
Saved each layer with EPSG 3857, WGS 84 Pseudo and then did it, again Angola.
Can anyone guess why? Or a suitable CRS that will mean it goes back to Somerset. Or do I accept and start anew?

Comment: What software are you using? Data offshore Africa sounds like the coordinates are in decimal degrees (GeoCRS) but defined as using a projected CRS.

Comment: QGIS 2.18.3...Though the project would of been set up on a much older program (2016 sometime). How do you check the coordinates to make sure that's not the case?